# SSIS: How to use project.params in WHERE clause

Tags: ssis

I have several packages and they all have the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE CreatedColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
```

I want to be able to change that value for all packages at the same time. So I added CreateDateTime in project.params as string with the value DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())

Then in my package variables I added SourceQuery with the actual query:

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedColumn >= " + @[$Project::CreatedDateTime] + ";"
```

In ExpressionBuilder I get the error:

> The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

If I change my actual query by removing the $ symbol into:

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedColumn >= " + @[Project::CreatedDateTime] + ";"
```

My error changes into:

> The variable "Project::CreatedDateTime" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.

Comment: I tested this and your first expression works fine for me - it's a very basic concatenation. What happens if you add just the parameter into the expression?

Comment: If I use SqlCommand and just do a plain SELECT... WHERE CreatedColumn >= @[$Project::CreatedDateTime] then I get the following error: 
_An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Must declare the scalar variable "@"."_

I'd like to add that my query is pretty long in terms of select and joins but it does only need that simple concatenation in WHERE.

Comment: I AM SORRY. I finally figured it out. There was a trailing sql comment at the bottom of the SqlCommand which was failing everything else. I did not enclose the sql comment in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Sql command: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedColumn >=?

and right click on the parameter tab and assign the variable Project::CreatedDateTime

Comment: Using an OLEDB Data Source, I tried the my Sql command with "?" parameter and got the following error:

_Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provider might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which the entire SQL command is stored in a variable_